# Ubuntu WebServer Disk Space suddenly increasing

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

We have a iWstack Cloud Service, with a main space of 100GB  and 20GB Side Storge.

NewRelic is always telling me that the main Space is full.

I check what is using this space with:

`sudo du -a /var/www | sort -n`

but everything looks healthy.

then I start flushing cache all around.

and notice that , when I do :

`RESET QUERY CACHE;
RESET MASTER;`

and restarting `NGINX` and `PHP5` will free space.

Is there any configuration on `my.cnf` that I'm missing ???

**UPDATE**

my.cnf:

```
# MariaDB database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this file to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /media/db/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
max_connections     = 100
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
#
# * MyISAM
#
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched. On error, make copy and try a repair.
myisam_recover          = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
# Cache only tiny result sets, so we can fit more in the query cache.
query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 64M
# for more write intensive setups, set to DEMAND or OFF
#query_cache_type       = DEMAND
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# we do want to know about network errors and such
log_warnings        = 2
#
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log[={0|1}]
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
#log_slow_rate_limit    = 1000
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#log_slow_admin_statements
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#report_host        = master1
#auto_increment_increment = 2
#auto_increment_offset  = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
# not fab for performance, but safer
#sync_binlog        = 1
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
# slaves
#relay_log      = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin
#relay_log_index    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.index
#relay_log_info_file    = /var/log/mysql/relay-bin.info
#log_slave_updates
#read_only
#
# If applications support it, this stricter sql_mode prevents some
# mistakes like inserting invalid dates etc.
#sql_mode       = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,TRADITIONAL
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
# you can't just change log file size, requires special procedure
#innodb_log_file_size   = 50M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: I wrote this article -maybe it will help you to investigate space usage http://main.org.ua/linux-check-disk-space-usage/

Comment: Let's disable query cache **query_cache_type=0;query_cache_size=0;** and keep monitoring how big this directory **/var/log/mysql/** is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL query cache has been originally designed 13 years ago, since then it didn't get an appropriate adaptation for newer software and hardware. Due to Percona experts [recommendation](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-settings-to-tune-after-installation/), keep it turned off all the time:

> query_cache_size: the query cache is a well known bottleneck that can
>   be seen even when concurrency is moderate. The best option is to
>   disable it from day 1 by setting query_cache_size = 0 (now the default
>   on MySQL 5.6) and to use other ways to speed up read queries: good
>   indexing, adding replicas to spread the read load or using an external
>   cache.

But this is pure performance recommendation, query cache doesn't consume hard drive space until it is really swapped.

What does **reset master** do for you, MySQL docs [says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reset-master.html):

> RESET MASTER removes all binary log files that are listed in the index
>   file, leaving only a single, empty binary log file with a numeric
>   suffix of .000001, whereas the numbering is not reset by PURGE BINARY
>   LOGS.

Share your **my.cnf** configuration to get more detailed instruction what to do next but if you say Reset Master helps the binary logs setup incorrectly.